# 10 parameters separated by comma. How can I do it?

Tags: parameters

```
\def\g(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9,#10){(#6)*exp(-(#2)/(#7))+((#6)**2)*exp(2*(-(#2))/(#7))*(#9)*exp((#4)/(#7)}%

\def\f(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9,#10){1+2*(#6)*exp(-(#2)/(#7))+((#6)**2)*exp(2*(-(#2))/(#7))*exp((#4)/(#7))}%

\def\h(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9,#10){2*(#10)*exp(-(#1)/(#7)) +exp( (#3)/(#7) )*( (#10)*exp(-(#1)/(#7) ) )^2 + 2*(#6)*exp(-(#2)/(#7))*(#10)*exp(-(#1)/(#7) )*exp((#5)/(#7)) }%

\def\v(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9,#10){( \g(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9,#10) + (#6)*exp(-(#2)/(#7))*(#10)*exp(-(#1)/(#7))*(#8)*exp((#5)/(#7)) )/(\f(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9,#10) + \h(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9,#10) )}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}

 \addplot[blue,mark=none,
         domain=0.0001:1,samples=300, line width=1]
    gnuplot { \v(0,(-10),0,0,0,x/10^3,1,1,1,1) }

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried that way and it didnot match the definition when a try to use \v

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. You need to show what you've tried.

Comment: the code above is exactly how i tried

Comment: @ThalesSouzaFreire That code can't work. Can you please add what the four functions should do with the ten parameters? Just pretend that `#10` can be used. Add it at the bottom of your question.

Comment: The question was edited

Comment: The main problem is that #10 is equivalent to {#1}0.  If you really want 10 comma delimited parameters, you will have to parse them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to do something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,pgfplots}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\E}{mm}
 {
  \clist_item:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\funcg}{m}
 {
  (\E{#1}{6})*exp(-(\E{#1}{2})/(\E{#1}{7}))+((\E{#1}{6})**2)*
  exp(2*(-(\E{#1}{2}))/(\E{#1}{7}))*(\E{#1}{9})*exp((\E{#1}{4})/(\E{#1}{7})
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\funcf}{m}
 {
  1+2*(\E{#1}{6})*exp(-(\E{#1}{2})/(\E{#1}{7}))+((\E{#1}{6})**2)*
  exp(2*(-(\E{#1}{2}))/(\E{#1}{7}))*exp((\E{#1}{4})/(\E{#1}{7}))
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\funch}{m}
 {
  2*(\E{#1}{10})*exp(-(\E{#1}{1})/(\E{#1}{7})) +
  exp( (\E{#1}{3})/(\E{#1}{7}) )*( (\E{#1}{10})*exp(-(\E{#1}{1})/(\E{#1}{7}) ) )^2 +
  2*(\E{#1}{6})*exp(-(\E{#1}{2})/(\E{#1}{7}))*(\E{#1}{10})*exp(-(\E{#1}{1})/(\E{#1}{7}) )*
  exp((\E{#1}{5})/(\E{#1}{7}))
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\funcv}{m}
 {
  (\funcg{#1} + (\E{#1}{6})*exp(-(\E{#1}{2})/(\E{#1}{7}))*
  (\E{#1}{10})*exp(-(\E{#1}{1})/(\E{#1}{7}))*(\E{#1}{8})*exp((\E{#1}{5})/(\E{#1}{7})) )/
  (\funcf{#1} + \funch{#1} )
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[blue,mark=none, domain=0.0001:1,samples=300, line width=1]
    gnuplot { \funcv{0,(-10),0,0,0,x/10^3,1,1,1,1} };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

where `\E{#1}{<number>}` stands for your `#<number>`.

Check the function definitions, because I get a gnuplot error; the expanded version seems to be

```
( (x/10^3)*exp(-((-10))/(1))+((x/10^3)**2)* exp(2*(-((-10)))/(1))*(1)*exp((
0)/(1)  + (x/10^3)*exp(-((-10))/(1))* (1)*exp(-(0)/(1))*(1)*exp((0)/(1)) )/ ( 1
+2*(x/10^3)*exp(-((-10))/(1))+((x/10^3)**2)* exp(2*(-((-10)))/(1))*exp((0)/(1))
  +  2*(1)*exp(-(0)/(1)) + exp( (0)/(1) )*( (1)*exp(-(0)/(1) ) )^2 + 2*(x/10^3)
*exp(-((-10))/(1))*(1)*exp(-(0)/(1) )* exp((0)/(1))  )
```